# TFS with VS 2005 and VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2005

I was instructed by System IT to start using TFS for source control. I have both VS 2005 and VS 2008 on my machine. I have NO idea how to go by setting my environment to use TFS. Can someone please enlighten me as to what all I need to do in order use TFS? (No they did not supply me with any instructions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of TFS. If it is TFS 2005 or TFS 2008 just use the Team Explorer panel (in menu view->team explorer) in visual studio 2008 to connect to TFS server. You have to know the TFS server name. If it is TFS 2010 you will need to install the forward compatibility pack for VS 2005 and VS 2008.

After connected select the team project you will have to work on and map a workspace path.

Comment: Thanks Pratik. We are using TFS 2008. My VS 2005 and 2008 is regular IDE. Not the one with TFS build in. Do you know any good links? I did a google and nothing good is coming out. Thanks. Bob (I dont see Team Explorer Panel in vs 2005 or 2008)

Comment: You need to install Team Explorer first. When you have done that, you have in the View menu the command "Team Explorer" which will open the Team Explorer window: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ed12659-3d41-4420-bbb0-a46e51bfca86&displaylang=en

Comment: So I guess I need to download 2 different Team Explorer. One for vs 2005 and one for vs 2008. Thanks for the help.